# Error --- #1396 - Operation CREATE USER failed for 'RegForm_user'@'%'

Tags: mysql

I have problem to create user running this sql script

```
CREATE DATABASE RegistrationForm
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;


CREATE USER RegForm_user;

GRANT ALL ON RegistrationForm.* TO 'RegForm_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '@regformpswd';

USE RegistrationForm

# *************** create tables *****************
```

I receive this error

```
    Errore
Query SQL:


CREATE USER RegForm_user
Messaggio di MySQL: Documentazione

#1396 - Operation CREATE USER failed for 'RegForm_user'@'%'
```

Why this error?

Comment: @Barmar I think this is different beacause in the database I have no user at all. I have just created the database. I cannot drop or delete any user because I'have NO USER !!!

Comment: The answer in the duplicate question says to use `FLUSH PRIVILIGES;` Did you try that?